# How to change date based on time?

Tags: pandas

**df**

```
date
2020-02-14 14:54:07
2020-02-12 17:01:31
2020-02-11 09:51:23
2020-02-11 08:51:23
2020-02-11 09:24:23
2020-02-11 00:24:27
2020-02-29 08:02:57
2020-03-13 08:44:10
```

**Goal**

```
date                     new_date
2020-02-14 14:54:07      2020-02-14
2020-02-12 17:01:31      2020-02-12
2020-02-11 09:51:23      2020-02-11
2020-02-11 08:51:23      2020-02-10
2020-02-11 09:24:23      2020-02-10
2020-02-11 00:24:27      2020-02-10
2020-02-29 08:02:57      2020-02-28
2020-03-13 08:44:10      2020-03-12
```

If time in `date` column is after '09:25:00', then the value of `new_date` is the same as `date` else the values is the last day of `date`.

Comment: Why is output `2020-02-10` and not `2020-02-11` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with compare times in strings and if necessary remove one day from minimal `date`:

```
t = '09:25:00'

m = df['date'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S').gt(t)
s = df['date'].dt.date
df['new_date'] = np.where(m, s, s.min() - pd.Timedelta(1, unit='days'))
#if need subtract one day
#df['new_date'] = np.where(m, s, s - pd.Timedelta(1, unit='days'))
print (df)
                 date    new_date
0 2020-02-14 14:54:07  2020-02-14
1 2020-02-12 17:01:31  2020-02-12
2 2020-02-11 09:51:23  2020-02-11
3 2020-02-11 08:51:23  2020-02-10
4 2020-02-11 09:24:23  2020-02-10
5 2020-02-11 00:24:27  2020-02-10
```

Solution with times:

```
from datetime import time

m = df['date'].dt.time.gt(time(9, 25))
s = df['date'].dt.date
df['new_date'] = np.where(m, s, s.min() - pd.Timedelta(1, unit='days'))
#if need subtract one day
#df['new_date'] = np.where(m, s, s - pd.Timedelta(1, unit='days'))
print (df)
                 date    new_date
0 2020-02-14 14:54:07  2020-02-14
1 2020-02-12 17:01:31  2020-02-12
2 2020-02-11 09:51:23  2020-02-11
3 2020-02-11 08:51:23  2020-02-10
4 2020-02-11 09:24:23  2020-02-10
5 2020-02-11 00:24:27  2020-02-10
```

Comment: I update my data. It's strange for new data if using 'np.where(m, s, s.min() - pd.Timedelta(1, unit='days'))', it will return '2019-12-31' . But it's ok while replace s.min() with s

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the previous date and not the last date you can use apply and check each date:

```
df["new_date"] = df.apply(lambda x: x.date.date() if x.date.time() > datetime.time(9,25) else x.date.date()-pd.DateOffset(days=-1), axis=1)
```

Comment: @jezrael I am fully aware of the pros and cons of apply. What are you trying to achieve by posting a link to a question as a comment here?

Comment: @jezrael Because depending on the _actual_ situation, it is 
a) potential a perfectly reasonable solution
b) useful to know about and a potential for someone to learn